# PrometheusOperator helm chart: metrics relabeling

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In my v33 Helm chart I need to drop the ID label in order to reduce the TSDB size. According to this [article](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/03/21/how-relabeling-in-prometheus-works/), this can be done with Metric Relabelings.  So in all  relevant sections of the values file I have the following:

```
metricRelabelings:
  - sourceLabels: [id]
    action: "drop"
```

In the resulting Prometheus config that I can see in the web GUI on port 9090, this gets translated (again in all relevant sections) as follows:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [id]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
```

However in the TSDB status in the GUI the "id" label is still there, with the same cardinality as before the attempt to drop it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this regex for drop metric with cpecific labels in my values.yaml in Prometheus operator chart. This works.

```html
kube-state-metrics:
  namespaceOverride: ""
  rbac:
    create: true
  releaseLabel: true
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      enabled: true

      ## Scrape interval. If not set, the Prometheus default scrape interval is used.
      ##
      interval: ""

      ## Scrape Timeout. If not set, the Prometheus default scrape timeout is used.
      ##
      scrapeTimeout: ""

      ## proxyUrl: URL of a proxy that should be used for scraping.
      ##
      proxyUrl: ""

      # Keep labels from scraped data, overriding server-side labels
      ##
      honorLabels: true

      ## MetricRelabelConfigs to apply to samples after scraping, but before ingestion.
      ## ref: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#relabelconfig
      ##
      metricRelabelings:
      - action: drop
        regex: '(default|test2|test1)'
        sourceLabels: [namespace]
```